# Setup an FAT12 floppy image with MBR

Tags: boot, partitioning, disk-image

I am following the [BrokenThorn tutorial](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev2.html) about OS development.
Windows is used in the tutorial, but I decided to use Ubuntu, because the build process is better.

Until now, I only had the program for the Master Boot Record.
I used a bash script to build

```
nasm -f bin -o boot.bin boot.asm
dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=boot.bin of=boot.flp
qemu-system-i386 -fda boot.flp
```

Now I am at a point where I want to load a second Stage bootloader. In the tutorial the floppy has a FAT12 filesystem. So I tried to adapt this in my build script

```
mkfs.vfat -F 12 ./boot.flp

sudo mount -o loop ./boot.flp /media/floppy1/
nasm -f bin -o STAGE2.SYS stage2.asm
sudo cp ./STAGE2.SYS /media/floppy1/
sudo umount /media/floppy1/

nasm -f bin -o boot.bin boot.asm
dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=boot.bin of=boot.flp

qemu-system-i386 -fda boot.flp
```

The image still boots, but when I try open the image as a loop device, Ubuntu drops an error

> mount: /media/floppy1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop16, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

So I think that the FAT12 is corrupted.
How can I setup a working FAT12 floppy image with my own Master Boot Record?

Answer (score 0):

Before creating file system, you have to partition the image and in your case to be a primary partition with bootable flag

Comment: I tried it manually with the 'fdisk' operation and then used the 'mkfs.vfat'. Then i used the dd command and tried again to mount the image. But i Get the following error: 'NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/loop17': Invalid argument
The device /dev/loop17 doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?'

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the things from the bios parameter block as options to the *mkfs.vfat* command. It is not necessary to create a partition.

```
mkfs.vfat -F 12 ./boot.flp -f 2 -h 0 -i 0xa0a1a2a3 -I -n "NAME OF OS " -r 224 -R 1 -s 1 -S 512
```